# React Native: businessPhoneNumber not persisting once saved

Tags: react-native

Whenever a user clicks on the **Business Information** link of my React Native application and attempts to update their business phone number, it does not save.

It will go through the process of saving in the UI, meaning that the user will see the spinner and then they get redirected back to the **My Membership** page, but when the user goes back to **Business Information**, the phone number is not there.

On the backend what is going on is the phone number gets updated, but then it re-renders with an empty phone number again:

```
{screenProps: undefined, navigation: {…}, businessName: "Ceramic Tile Distributors", businessWebsite: "", businessPhoneNumber: "512-222-5555", …}

{businessName: "", businessPhoneNumber: ""}
```

The **Business Details** component is as follows:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { View, Alert } from "react-native";
import BusinessDetailsForm from "membership/components/BusinessDetailsForm";
import { ModalSpinner } from "common-components";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  updateInformation,
  handleDetailsChanged,
  toggleSameAddresses,
  setInitialData,
  resetBusiness,
  resetMailing
} from "membership/actions";
import regex from "utils/helpers/regex";

export class BusinessDetails extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    businessName: PropTypes.string,
    businessPhoneNumber: PropTypes.string,
    handleDetailsChanged: PropTypes.func,
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    resetBusiness: PropTypes.func,
    resetBusinessAddress: PropTypes.bool,
    resetMailing: PropTypes.func,
    resetMailingAddress: PropTypes.bool,
    setInitialData: PropTypes.func,
    toggleSameAddresses: PropTypes.func,
    updateInformation: PropTypes.func,
    userOrganization: PropTypes.object
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      displaySpinner: false,
      validationErrors: {},
      displayErrors: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setInitialData(this.props.userOrganization);
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      "willFocus",
      () => {
        this._resetEmptyFields();
      }
    );
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.displayErrors) {
      this._validate(nextProps);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
  }

  _resetEmptyFields = () => {
    if (this.props.resetBusinessAddress) {
      this.props.resetBusiness(this.props.userOrganization);
    }
    if (this.props.resetMailingAddress) {
      this.props.resetMailing(this.props.userOrganization);
    }
  };

  _validate = props => {
    console.log(props);
    const validationErrors = {
      businessName: props.businessName ? "" : "Is Required",
      businessPhoneNumber:
        props.businessPhoneNumber.length === 0 ||
        regex.phoneNumber.test(props.businessPhoneNumber)
          ? ""
          : "Phone number must be valid and contain 10 digits"
    };
    console.log(validationErrors);
    const isValid = Object.keys(validationErrors).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      console.log(isValid);
      if (validationErrors[curr] !== "") {
        return false;
      }

      return acc;
    }, true);

    this.setState({ validationErrors, displayErrors: !isValid });
    return isValid;
  };

  _saveChanges = () => {
    const isValid = this._validate(this.props);
    console.log(isValid);

    if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ displaySpinner: true });
      this.props
        .updateInformation()
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ displaySpinner: false }, () => {
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          Alert.alert(
            "Error",
            this.props.businessPhoneNumber.length === 0
              ? "Please provide a business phone number. If your business phone number no longer exists, please call 1-800-NFIB-NOW to have this information deleted."
              : "We couldn't save your changes. Please try again.",
            [
              {
                text: "OK",
                onPress: () => this.setState({ displaySpinner: false })
              }
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          );
        });
    }
  };

  _businessNameChanged = businessName => {
    this.props.handleDetailsChanged({ businessName });
  };

  _businessWebsiteChanged = businessWebsite => {
    this.props.handleDetailsChanged({ businessWebsite });
  };

  _businessPhoneNumberChanged = businessPhoneNumber => {
    this.props.handleDetailsChanged({ businessPhoneNumber });
  };

  _navigateBussiness = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("BusinessAddress");
  };

  _navigateMailing = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("MailingAddress");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ModalSpinner visible={this.state.displaySpinner} color={"purple"} />
        <BusinessDetailsForm
          {...this.props}
          businessNameChanged={this._businessNameChanged}
          businessWebsiteChanged={this._businessWebsiteChanged}
          businessPhoneNumberChanged={this._businessPhoneNumberChanged}
          changeBussinessAddressNavigation={this._navigateBussiness}
          changeMailingAddressNavigation={this._navigateMailing}
          saveChanges={this._saveChanges}
          errors={this.state.validationErrors}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapState2Props = ({ membership, auth }) => {
  return {
    ...membership.businessDetails,
    userOrganization: auth.userOrganization
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapState2Props,
  {
    handleDetailsChanged,
    updateInformation,
    toggleSameAddresses,
    setInitialData,
    resetMailing,
    resetBusiness
  }
)(BusinessDetails);
```

So when I save the phone number, this piece of data:

```
{screenProps: undefined, navigation: {…}, businessName: "Ceramic Tile Distributors", businessWebsite: "", businessPhoneNumber: "512-222-5555", …}
```

is now updated inside of `props` here:

```
_validate = props => {
    const validationErrors = {
      businessName: props.businessName ? "" : "Is Required",
      businessPhoneNumber:
        props.businessPhoneNumber.length === 0 ||
        regex.phoneNumber.test(props.businessPhoneNumber)
          ? ""
          : "Phone number must be valid and contain 10 digits"
    };
```

Then I am not entirely sure what is happening but the object inside that `validationErrors` seems to re-render the data without the phone number I just added.

{businessName: "", businessPhoneNumber: ""}

and `isValid` here:

```
const isValid = Object.keys(validationErrors).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (validationErrors[curr] !== "") {
    return false;
  }

  return acc;
}, true);
```

returns `undefined`.

But by the time it gets down here:

```
_saveChanges = () => {
    const isValid = this._validate(this.props);

if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ displaySpinner: true });
      this.props
        .updateInformation()
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ displaySpinner: false }, () => {
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          Alert.alert(
            "Error",
            this.props.businessPhoneNumber.length === 0
              ? "Please provide a business phone number. If your business phone number no longer exists, please call 1-800-NFIB-NOW to have this information deleted."
              : "We couldn't save your changes. Please try again.",
            [
              {
                text: "OK",
                onPress: () => this.setState({ displaySpinner: false })
              }
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          );
        });
    }
```

`isValid` is `true`.

Comment: What are you passing into your ```BusinessDetailsForm``` component as the businessPhoneNumber prop?

Comment: @Jono, when I `console.log(props.businessPhoneNumber);`, I get this: `{number: "(919)555-1212", type: "Business", Number: "(919)555-1212", Type: "Business"}`.

Comment: There's your issue then. You've declared the prop type as a string, but you're passing in an object.

Comment: The problem is in the parent of ```BusinessDetailsForm```. Whatever you're passing into the ```businessPhoneNumber``` property is an object. You should pass in ```businessPhoneNumber.number``` instead.

Comment: Alternatively declare your ```businessPhoneNumber``` property type as ```PropTypes.object``` in ```BusinessDetaiolsForm``` and then pass ```businessPhoneNumber.number``` into your ```Input``` component.

Comment: @Jono, I just tried your alternative solution which sounded fair and simple enough, when I log out the input I get just the phone number, no object, but if I do `businessPhoneNumber: PropTypes.object,`  the error tells me I gave it an object and it expected a string, or `businessPhoneNumber: PropTypes.string,`, then I get a warning saying I gave it a string when it expected an object. Both times the input has been `value={props.businessPhoneNumber.number}`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Not sure why that's happening. It should work the same as your ```shortMailingAddress``` prop, which is an object on your ```BusinessDetailsForm```  and then you're passing in the string values into the child components which are expecting a string prop.

Comment: @Jono, what would you do to get to the bottom of why that is happening?

Comment: It's a tricky one, as it should be working from what I can gather from the other code. I would remove the types all the way from your main parent to your children, use dummy values (try both object & string values), get it working, and then slowly add types (and your variable values) back from the children up. That way you can pinpoint exactly where the issue lies (or what a working solution should look like with types), using static dummy values, and then manipulate your data to work with the working version.

Comment: @Jono, can you provide a concrete example of what you wrote in your comments as the answer. I would like to implement what you suggested in my debugging process, but some concrete examples would help.

Comment: Please trim down the question, there is so much to read in this question and some huge images, but you are not sharing what data is being sent to the component that has the proptype defined, nor what that data might be (except in the comments). If you have an object you pass in, you would declare it as a `businessPhoneNumber: PropTypes.shape({ number: PropTypes.string })`. There might be some things you need to learn still. Note that what you are seeing is a warning, it correctly informs you something is wrong, and it gives really good indication to what is wrong, be curious what it tells you

Comment: @Icepickle, I will trim down the question. Thanks for looking into it. I am sure I have plenty to learn, with that said fyi I am not the original author of this code, so that's part of my headache, I would have written this differently. Stay tuned for changes.